# GridView Gallery inside Dialog Android

Tags: android, gridview, dialog, gallery, android-gallery

Hello I want to build simple Gallery by using GridView. I want to place it inside Dialog. I wrote some code but all it doesn't work. I get error that adapter is empty. How should it looks like ? For now my codes looks like :

GuidePhotoAlbum code :

```
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;
    GridView gV;
    public ArrayList<File> list;

    public class GuidePhotoAlbum extends Activity
    {
        @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.guide_photo_album);
            list = imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    }
private ArrayList<File> imageReader(File root)
{
    ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
        if(files[i].isDirectory())
        {
            a.addAll(imageReader(files[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
            {
                a.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}

    public void onClickk(View v)
{
   openDialog2();
}

    public void openDialog2() {


            inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_choice, null);
            gV = new GridView(this);
            gV = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            gV.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder2.setTitle("MY GALLERY");
            builder2.setView(v).setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder2.setCancelable(false);
            builder2.create().show();
        }
```

GridAdapter :

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    GuidePhotoAlbum guidePhotoAlbum = new GuidePhotoAlbum();
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return guidePhotoAlbum.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return guidePhotoAlbum.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = guidePhotoAlbum.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_grid,parent,false);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()));
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Xml dialog_choice file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_choice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

xml my_grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try DialogFragment

Comment: what's wrong with this one ?

Comment: make sure your  guidePhotoAlbum.list.size() > 0. Add log to adapter's getCount() method to check the size of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update `GridAdapter` as below:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<File> listFiles;

    public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> files) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.listFiles = files;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listFiles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.my_grid, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listFiles.get(position).toString()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**From `GuidePhotoAlbum` activity pass `context` and `list` to `GridAdapter`:**

```
    public void openDialog2() {

        inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Dialog layout
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_choice, null);

        // Get gridView from dialog_choice
        gV = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        // GridAdapter (Pass context and files list)
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, list);

        // Set adapter
        gV.setAdapter(adapter);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder2.setTitle("MY GALLERY");
        builder2.setView(v);
        builder2.setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder2.setCancelable(false);
        builder2.create().show();
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: It works :) Now I have jsut problem with memory :) need to decode this files. Should I do this in ImageReader method ?

Comment: Better you can use Glide library to load image efficiently. Its very easy to use. See documentation: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: but still I should do it inside this method yea ?

Comment: Of-course you should set image from adapters getView() method.

Comment: Still I'm confused how should I do that and what will be best way.

Comment: First, getView() will return the list item view. So you must set image from getView(). Second, to resolve outofmemory error you can use very well known library Glide or Picasso or you can make your own using bitmap decoding methods. If still you are confused then its better to raise a question about this scenario. Hope you will get solution asap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144355/discussion-between-ferdous-ahamed-and-kyluace).